# Using GPIO (leds) for bringup board

Tags: linux, gpio

I'm trying to bring up a custom board with OMAP L132.
Almost all the times something crash before the serial display after "booting the kernel"
I couldn't figure out what cause the crashing from the log_buf (printk outputs) so I tried (and I'm still trying) to use the leds I have on board.
The leds are connected by GPIOs. As far as I understand the kernel can't access physical memory directly and I need to pass through some mapping to kernel virtual address.
However, when I'm trying to configure the GPIO in start_kernel function it crash. the ioremap(...), the gpio_direction_output(...) crash with error regarding the SLUB (unable to allocate memory node -1 ; SLUB: Genslabs=11, HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1)
I'm just trying accessing registers for controlling GPIO, which initialization did I miss here? What is the earliest point that GPIO can access in the kernel? Should I initialize something in the uboot for that?

Thanks in advance,
Arie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently, there some initialization that need to pass before  GPIO registers (or any register) can be access easily. before the call to rest_init function there's no problem with init and play with those registers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to look into "earlyprintk" kernel mechanism, it should do the trick. If it's not applicable in your case, read further.

If you want to control GPIO directly via registers (like in bare-metal application, i.e. not using kernel GPIO framework), you should do next stuff:

1. Enable clocks for your GPIO module (see "Power, Reset and Clock Management" chapter in your TRM)
2. Configure pin muxes, so that pins (that you have connected to your LEDS) are connected to GPIO module (see "Control Module" in your TRM)
3. Since kernel works only with virtual addresses, you need to obtain virtual addresses for your GPIO registers using ioremap() function
4. Now you should be able to use iowrite32() and ioread32() macros to interact with GPIO register virtual addresses you have remapped on previous step

AFAIR, procedure described above can be found in GPIO chapter (more specifically, in "Programming Manual" sub-chapter) in TRM for your SoC.

If you want to use kernel GPIO framework, you also need to be sure first that clocks and muxes configured properly. Next you should find GPIO driver for your SoC (something like this: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-omap.c) and enable it in your config (must be probably enabled by default if you are using defconfig for your board). Now, you can only use GPIO framework functions when your GPIO driver is loaded. "gpio-omap" driver is being probed in postcore_initcall (which is level 2), so you can only start to use it from next level of initcall. AFAIU, this is not sufficient in your case, because you are trying to debug kernel on earliest initcall levels.